# If X is regular, every pair of points of X have neighbourhoods whose closures are disjoint.

Tags: general-topology

Even before we think about closures, for this to be possible, every regular space has to be Haussdorf right. But we know that all regular spaces are not Haussdorf. So what am I getting wrong?

Comment: What is your definition of regular?

Comment: Some people, unfortunately, use *regular* to mean what is properly called $T_3$: instead of using it to mean that if $p$ is a point not in a closed set $F$, then $p$ and $F$ have disjoint open nbhds, they use it to mean this plus $T_1$. Worse yet, they use $T_3$ to mean what is propertly called *regular*, so that the $T_n$ no longer form a hierarchy. That’s what is happening here: someone is using *regular* to mean $T_3$, i.e., regular + $T_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here  regular means $T_3+T_1$.